# Adding headers to a LWP post in Perl

Tags: perl, header, lwp

I have taken over some perl code and been asked to add a keep-alive header to the LWP post that happens.

Google tells me how to do this for certain setups, but I can't see how to do it for the way this code has been written. All the info I can find works on the basis of creating the LWP object, then creating the POST and parameters, then adding the headers, then actually POSTING the request, however in the code I have to deal with, the creating of the POST, adding the headers and sending are all in one line:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post( $URL, ['parm1'=>'val1']);
```

How/where can I add the headers in this setup, or do I need to re-write as per the examples I have found?

Comment: I would suggest a re-write.  That way it will be more maintainable and you can add whatever level of control to it that you want.

Comment: If I can avoid it, I'd prefer to - the code's been stable for a while and will be completely replaced by a new system in the next six months - I have just been asked to add this one header to speed things up in the interim and don't want to risk new issues by rewriting if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`LWP::UserAgent`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) page tells you how to do this. You would set the handler [`request_prepare`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#request_prepare) on the user agent object. That will pass you in the **request** object before it posts.

Actually, anything you put as a list of key-value pairs before the key `'Content'` followed by the structure that you want to post, will translate into headers, per [**`HTTP::Request::Common::POST`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon#POST)

```
 $ua->post( $URL, keep_alive => 1, Content => ['parm1'=>'val1']);
```

Or without the content tag, if you put the structure first, you can put header key-value pairs after:

```
 $ua->post( $URL, ['parm1'=>'val1'], keep_alive => 1 );
```

Comment: This is wrong. adding keep_alive => 1 just makes a "Keep-Alive: 1" header which has nothing to do with persistent connections, where it should do "Connection: keep-alive". Just make a tcpdump and you see that every HTTP requests does its own TCP connection, contrary to what keep alive should do.

Answer (score 1):

Did they really asked you to add a keep-alive header only, or did they ask you to support keep alive, e.g. multiple HTTP requests within the same TCP connection. In the latter case you should use (according to the documentation of LWP::UserAgent):

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 10 );
$ua->get('http://foo.bar/page1');
$ua->get('http://foo.bar/page2');   # reuses connection from previous request
```

In this case it will keep at most 10 connections open at the same time. If you only do requests do the same site you can also set it to 1 so that it reuses the same TCP connection for all requests.

A Keep-Alive header has no meaning, what keep_alive => 1 within the user agent does is set up a connection cache and add a "Connection: keep-alive" header (with HTTP/1.1 keep-alive is implicite, so it does not need to add the header for HTTP/1.1 requests).

Comment: They asked me to add the keep-alive header. I have no idea if they meant to support keep-alive, but after following the advice of @Axeman, it seems to be faster. I will ask them if they actually meant this :)

Comment: Nope, @Axeman is wrong. Just do a tcpdump and you see that it does not reuse the TCP connection for multiple requests.

Comment: ok, @Axeman is not really wrong. His code adds a Keep-Alive header which is what you asked for, but which is probably not the task they gave you (e.g. reuse connections with keep-alive). All it does is add a  header nobody uses.